# UISearchBar with scope buttons NSInternalInconsistencyException Crash on Cancel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm at sort of a loss here.

I have a UISearchBar with two scope buttons Option A and Option B. Searching works just fine on both scope buttons but when I click Cancel out of the search bar with the second scope button selected the app will *sometimes* crash with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 3 in section at index 0'
```

Here's the relevant code for my UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray *results = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView && [[fetchedResultsController sections] count] > section) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray *alphabet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UITableViewIndexSearch, @"A", @"B", @"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",@"#",nil];
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return alphabet;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if(tableView == self.tableView && [title isEqual:UITableViewIndexSearch]){
        [tableView scrollRectToVisible:[[tableView tableHeaderView] bounds] animated:NO];
        return -1;
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return [self.fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles indexOfObject:title];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OptionACell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSManagedObject *category = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == CategoriesViewSearchScopeOptionB && ![self.searchBar.text isEqual:@""]) {
        [cell.textLabel setText:[category valueForKey:@"text"]];
    } else {
        [cell.textLabel setText:[category valueForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And the UISearchBar:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if([self.searchBar.text isEqual: @""] && self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == CategoriesViewSearchScopeOptionB) {
        self.searchBar.text=@"";
        [self updateOptionAFetchRequest];
    } else {
        [self updateFetchRequest];
        NSFetchedResultsController *fetchController = [self fetchedResultsController];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar {
    [self logSearchTerm:self.searchBar.text];
    self.searchBar.text = @"";
    self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = CategoriesViewSearchScopeOptionA;
    [self updateOptionAFetchRequest];

    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = nil;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self logSearchTerm:self.searchBar.text];
    if([self.searchBar.text isEqual: @""]) self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = CategoriesViewSearchScopeOptionA;
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope {
    if([self.searchBar.text length] > 0) {
        [self updateFetchRequest];
    }
}

- (void)updateFetchRequest {
if (self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex == CategoriesViewSearchScopeOptionB) {
    [self updateOptionBFetchRequest];
    return;
}
[self updateOptionAFetchRequest];
}
```

I'm having trouble discerning the exact pattern of the crashing. It seems to crash consistently whenever I perform the action of opening the UISearchBar, clicking OptionB then Canceling. But when I open the SearchBar, click back and forth between the scope buttons and perform a couple searches, I'm able to close no problem.

Any help from Core Data experts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are modifying your fetchedResultsController while searching. So, when you press Cancel, the FRC has not been updated to pre-search condition and so sometimes it crashes (depending on what the search criteria is).... Use a separate FRC for search

Comment: I think you have a good point there. I'll try it out and let you know how it works.